# Sources to learn about discrete probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Are there any good, free online sources where I can learn about discrete probability, probability theory, Bayes' theorem, etc.?

Topics that I'm mainly interested in:

Probabilities of complements/unions

Problems such as the Monty Hall problem

Conditional probability

Independence

Bernoulli trials/distributions

Random variables

And other introductory topics associated with discrete probability theory.

Thank you!

Comment: Dr Gallager's book (draft version) on Discrete Stochastic Processes is available here: http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/notes.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried iTunes U, Khan Academy, etc.? Also, nowadays many universities have YouTube channels with free lectures. You might want to try that if you prefer to watch someone explain. I would recommend Great Courses, but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Selected parts of Kyle Siegrist's [Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics](http://www.randomservices.org/random/) may be helpful